# DDD example: is this kind of logic is "allowed" in service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, domain-driven-design

I am trying, as an exercise, to build a small sample app using DDD and clean code:

By applying the rule that an aggregate should not hold references to entities of other aggregates, but rather just their IDs, I find myself having this kind of logic in the service layer:

```
public class StockService implements StockServicePort {

    private final StockRepo stockRepo;

    private final CategoryRepo categoryRepo;

    private final FinhubPort finhubPort;

    public static final String STOCK_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE = "Stock not found, id: ";

    @Override
    public StockWithExternalData getStockById(String stockId) {
        final Stock existingStock = stockRepo.findStockById(stockId);
        if (existingStock == null) {
            throw new StockNotFoundException("Stock requested not found, id: " + stockId);
        }
        final BigDecimal externalPrice = finhubPort.getStockPriceByName(existingStock.getName());
        final Category category = categoryRepo.findCategoryById(existingStock.getCategoryId() == null ? "-" : existingStock.getCategoryId()); // is this OK ?
        String categoryName = "not present";
        if(category != null) {
            categoryName = category.getName();
        }
        return new StockWithExternalData(existingStock.getUuid(), existingStock.getName(), categoryName, existingStock.getValue(), externalPrice);
    }

    @Override
    public String addStock(NewStockCommand newStockCommand) {
        final Category category = this.categoryRepo.findCategoryByName(newStockCommand.getCategoryName()); // is this OK ?
        String categoryId = null;
        if(category != null) {
            categoryId = category.getUuid();
        }
        final Stock stock = new Stock(newStockCommand.getName(), newStockCommand.getValue(), categoryId);
        this.stockRepo.save(stock);
        return stock.getUuid();
    }
```

Is the logic that loads the category, to make sure it exists and to retrieve the id, supposed to be here ?

As I understand this logic should not live in the Model classes, so the service layer, a.k.a. application layer, seems the place for it, but I am not really sure and wanted to ask you about best practices in such cases.

**Disclaimer**: I don't think this question is "opinion based", I am asking what is the DDD "rule" in such a case and if this logic could be considered fitting according to DDD.

Comment: Like every design "framework", DDD makes assumptions about the universe that just aren't true in real life.  For instance, the idea that aggregate roots form a nice well-behaved forest of trees, when the real world is a chaotic mess of networks.  You can force inter-tree references to be resolved via the aggregate root, but you may end up with severe performance issues (which probably means that your domain model was wrong to begin with).  All design dicta apply until they don't, and the real genius is knowing when to break the rules.  i.e. there is no one "rule" to rule them all.

Comment: I don't think you are going to find an authoritative answer.  Using unlocked data to (a) create a response to a query or (b) renormalize some inputs are both fine?  and since you need I/O to access the "lookup table", then putting the code in the part of your design where the other I/O concerns live makes a lot of sense, whereas putting that I/O code in the model... doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we disregard the topic of aggregate modeling, as there isn't sufficient context to delve into it, your code looks consistent with what DDD recommends for the application layer.

The app layer is an acceptable place to orchestrate interactions between aggregates and repositories. This includes fetching the necessary data like you do. Sometimes, the logic might become too complex to be in the application layer. In such cases, moving some of the logic into a Domain Service is possible. These are different from services that belong to the domain layer and encapsulate domain-specific operations that don't naturally fit within an entity or value object. In that scenario, the app layer service retrieves all the necessary data and delegates the processing to the domain service.

To sum up, your code looks good to me. But for more complex scenarios, you can consider using domain services.